# Can you swap styles for items during runtime in Android?

Tags: android, colors, themes

So, I haven't really messed around with using the styles.xml before, and I was wondering weither I might be able to use it do color themes?
And weither I would be able to change this during runtime.

Lets say I want a red theme and a blue theme.
Is there some way to do this somehow?

```
<style name="RedTheme" parent="@style/TrueFullscreen">
    <color name="Background">#FF0000</color>
</style>

<style name="BlueTheme" parent="@style/TrueFullscreen">
    <color name="Background">#0000FF</color>
</style>
```

And then at some point during runtime say `hey, app! style="RedTheme"`

I know I can use this as sort of a css equivalent to style multiple elements. But can it be used this way too? Or is there another elegant way I could solve this color theme problem?